# Get sprite to stay on screen?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

How do I get my sprite to remain on the screen and on the green platform?
The sprite keeps falling off the screen, can anyone help please?

```
player_image = pygame.image.load("bcquestchar.png")
player_image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
def draw_background(screen, x, y):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, ground_GREEN, [0, 400], [700, 400], 200)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, sky_BLUE, [0,0], [700,0], 400)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, sky_WHITE, [0, 270], [700, 270], 150)

#jumping player definition 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.playing = False
        self.color = BLUE
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 210
        self.goalY= 450
        self.gameover = False
    def jump(self):
        self.goalY -= 45
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(player_image, [self.x, self.y])       

#create player
player = Player()
```

Comment: see "Platformer Example" on http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38

Comment: first use [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for every element to keep its position and size then you can use "collision detection" function build-in `pygame.Rect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make another function to make sure that when your sprite's bottom is touching the bottom of the screen, it stops there, waiting for any other commands. For example:

```
if self.x >= 1000:    
    self.x = 1000
```

The above code means that if the `x` position is greater than or equal to 1000, then set `x` to 1000 so it doesn't go any lower. The number can change to fit your needs as well. You will also need to call the `update` function as we need it to work:

```
def update(self):        #Put the function into your Player class
    if self.x >= 1000:
        self.x = 1000

#Put the following the while loop or just call it
player = Player()
player.update()    #Call update()
```

Comment: Do I add the function to the sprite? If so, I tried it and it didn't seem to work unfortunately :-( The size of the screen is 700x400 so I made the function that if the y position exceeds 400, it is set to 400 and can't go any lower yet it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @MichaelNguyen you have to check player position after you move it. In your question there is no code where you move player - so answer can't be more precised.

Answer (score 0):

After you move player you have to check its position and correct it.

You should use `pygame.Rect` because it helps.

It is not complet code and it doesn't use `rect` methods to check collisions but it shows how to start it.

```
# jumping player definition

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        self.image = pygame.image.load("bcquestchar.png")
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        self.playing = False
        self.color = BLUE

        # use rect to keep size and position
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 50
        self.rect.y = 210

        self.goalY= 450
        self.gameover = False

        #self.speed_x = 0
        #self.speed_y = 0
        #self.gravity = 1

    def jump(self):
        self.goalY -= 45

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)       

    #def event_handler(self, event):
    #    # if pressed key then change speed

    def update(self):
        # move player 
        #self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        #self.rect.y += self.speed_y

        #self.speed_y += self.gravity

        # check collision with grass
        if self.rect.bottom > grass_rect.top:

            # player below grass then move it up
            self.rect.bottom = grass_rect.top:

# ---

# draw other objects
def draw_background(screen, x, y):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, ground_GREEN, grass_rect, 200)

# ---

# create player
player = Player()

# create object rect to draw it and check collision with player
grass_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 400, 700, 400)

# move player and check collision with objects
player.update()
```

You have player `rect` and grass `rect` - you can compare player bottom with grass `top`.

See more in source code of "[Platformer Example](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38)"